# DropDownList Databind Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I am binding data for DropDownList in asp.net. The code doesn't seem to work.
 the Error is
[Click here to see the error, data does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0RHR.jpg)

I have three entries in the table "Users".
Connection String is correct, i am positive.

```
   SqlConnection ddlcon = new SqlConnection(strncon);
            ddlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username from Users", ddlcon);
            SqlDataAdapter ddlAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ddl = new DataTable();
            ddlAdp.Fill(ddl);
            ddlMembers.DataSource = ddl;
            ddlMembers.DataBind();
            ddlcon.Close();
```

Comment: why you tagged `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the dropdown but you are not telling it what values from your data source to show. You need to set the DataTextField and DataValueField properties to determine what text values to show and what value to select when choosing in the dropdown.

For example:

```
SqlConnection ddlcon = new SqlConnection(strncon);
ddlcon.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username from Users", ddlcon);
SqlDataAdapter ddlAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable ddl = new DataTable();
ddlAdp.Fill(ddl);

ddlMembers.DataSource = ddl;
ddlMembers.DataTextField = "Username";
ddlMembers.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlMembers.DataBind();
ddlcon.Close();
```

This is assuming your user description is named 'Username' and the primary key on your users table is 'Id', please change these to correspond to your table columns.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: Set ddlMembers.DataTextField to whatever the name of the column from your table that you want to display is, and do the same for the value field.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ToString()-Method of the class DataTable to return the data you want to see.

Comment: i didn't get it, can you write me an example

Comment: public override string ToString(){ return "i am a value"; } in the DataTable class.